# How to increment Firebase Realtime database data values by one in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime database like this.

`myRoot
  |--- mykey1
  |     |---myValue: 1
  |
  |--- mykey2
  |     |---myValue: 0
  |
  |--- mykey3
        |---myValue: 2`

I need to increment all these values by one and get the following output.

`myRoot
  |--- mykey1
  |     |---myValue: 2
  |
  |--- mykey2
  |     |---myValue: 1
  |
  |--- mykey3
        |---myValue: 3`

How I can do this using a loop? Or, what is the best way to do this in React Native?

The actual thing what I want is this. Let's think, I have a home screen. It has a button called "List values". When I clicked, I navigate to the next page (Stack navigator) and there, it displays the values of myKey1, myKey2, myKey3. It is a flatlist. Let's think there is a button called "Increment values" in that second sreen. When I pressed it, I want to increment the values and navigate back to the home screen.

I've tried something like this.

```
let arr = ['myKey1' , 'myKey2' , 'myKey3']

try {
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     let ref = firebase.database().ref(myRoot).child(arr[i]);
     ref.transaction( function(myValue) {
        return (myValue || 0) + 1;
     })
  }
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(error));
}
```

It changes the values in the database as I expect. But, it gives the following yellow warning after execution.

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method

This is a sample model to explain what I need.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you are calling to: `.then(() => this.props.navigation.goBack());` in each iteration. I think that you need to use a `runTransaction` as documented in [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions).

Samples are for a structure like:

```
myRoot
  |--- mykey1: number
```

For a structure like this:

```
myRoot
  |--- mykey1
  |     |---myValue: number
```

you should use the next `const ref` declaration instead:

```
const ref = db.ref(myRoot).child(key).child('myValue');
```

## Sample Firestore

```
const arr = ['myKey1' , 'myKey2' , 'myKey3'];
const db = firebase.database();

db.runTransaction(transaction => {
    return Promise.all(arr.map(key => {
      const ref = db.ref(myRoot).child(key);
      return transaction
        .get(ref)
        .then(val => transaction.update(ref, (val || 0) + 1));
    }));
  })
  .then(() => this.props.navigation.goBack())
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

## Sample Realtime Database

```
const arr = ['myKey1' , 'myKey2' , 'myKey3'];
const db = firebase.database();

Promise.all(arr.map(key => {
    const ref = db.ref(myRoot).child(key);
    return ref.transaction(function(myValue) {
      return (myValue || 0) + 1;
    })
  }))
  .then(() => this.props.navigation.goBack())
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this didn't work. Didn't update the values. Any other solution, please?

Comment: I've updated the code I tried. Still, it works and changes the values as I expect. But, give the same yellow warning.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've answered with Firestore in mind. I've just edited with a version using your code that waits until all the promises are completed.

Comment: I tried this code also. But, it didn't work. After execution, the database was changed like this.       `myKey1: 
"[object Object]1"
myKey2: 
"[object Object]1"
myKey3: 
"[object Object]1"`

Comment: That's because your updating code is for the structure `myRoot -> myKeyN -> number`. If your database structure is `myRoot -> myKeyN -> myValue -> number` it will show your result. To achieve your desired result with the second structure, you should append `.child('myValue')` to `const ref = db.ref(myRoot).child(key);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution also works well. But, still gives the yellobox. Finally, I managed to disable that warning. It's ok now. Can you please, explain me, which method is better? Your solution or, the way I posted in my question?

Comment: Have in mind that your yellow box may be caused by something else. About which is better:  It's preferable to wait for all the promises before you call `.goBack()`. In your code, the try catch does almost nothing and the `.goBack()` runs synchronously just after the loop and not after the values are updated in Realtime Database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193374/discussion-between-danpeis-and-sennen-randika).